# Adding targets in Apache ACE

Tags: osgi-bundle, apache-ace, remote-management

I'm trying to use Apache ACE web UI to remotely manage OSGi bundles on Raspberry PI devices. I followed the documentations [here](http://ace.apache.org/user-doc/user-guide.html)  but I can't find out how to actually add a target (RPi) to the server (which is my PC).

To be clearer, I downloaded the apache-ace.bin package in my PC and copied a version in the RPi. Then ran the ACE server (`java -jar server-allinone.jar`) in the PC and the ACE target (`java -jar target.jar`) in the RPi. Then here, `http://127.0.0.1:8080/ace/` I created one sample artifact and target, suppose named target-1. Now my question is how can I bind this target with that target which is running in my RPi? I'm not sure if me or this documentation is missing some points here.

I tried ProSyst mPRM cloud earlier which was very easy to use but I want to try an open source one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using the just released 2.0.1 version. If you create a target called "target-1" in the UI, what you need to do is make sure that the target you start on the RPi is also called "target-1" because by default it will be called "defaultTargetID". You can specify the name as a command line parameter. You probably also need to specify the location of the server (which defaults to localhost):

```
java -Dagent.identification.agentid=target-1 -Dagent.discovery.serverurls=http://your.ace.host:8080 -jar target.jar
```

If you want to learn more about running a target and what you can configure, I highly recommend checking out this page/section:

http://ace.apache.org/user-doc/user-guide.html#running-a-target

Comment: Thank you (both for your answer here and your videos in YouTube). I wish there could be such exact example in the documentations also. Though it also proves I was not reading carefully that part of documentations.

Comment: Where would you have expected this information to be? I could add it to this page for example? http://ace.apache.org/user-doc/getting-started.html

Comment: I think you can add it here: http://ace.apache.org/user-doc/user-guide.html#running-a-target ; after all those command line options as an example. Also you can insert a link to that part here: http://ace.apache.org/user-doc/getting-started.html#start-an-ace-target ; Another point which I guess is a bit confusing for new comers, in the "Start an ACE target" section you can start with "In your target device.." or something like that. Thank you :)

Comment: I've added an example on how to start the management agent on your target, resolving ACE-474. See http://ace.apache.org/user-doc/user-guide.html#running-a-target.